# Set a default, catch-all custom endpoint for AWS Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, localstack

I am trying to apply terraform to an AWS localstack instance running on `http://localhost:4566`. This means overwriting the `endpoints` on the "aws" provider, as described in the docs [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/3.63.0/docs/guides/custom-service-endpoints#getting-started-with-custom-endpoints).

However, to be safe this requires manually specifying the endpoint to every service, leaving me with this...

```
provider "aws" {
  region              = "ap-southeast-2"
  s3_force_path_style = true

  access_key                  = "fake"
  secret_key                  = "fake"
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true

  endpoints {
    accessanalyzer           = "http://localhost:4566"
    acm                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    acmpca                   = "http://localhost:4566"
    amplify                  = "http://localhost:4566"
    apigateway               = "http://localhost:4566"
    applicationautoscaling   = "http://localhost:4566"
    applicationinsights      = "http://localhost:4566"
    appmesh                  = "http://localhost:4566"
    appstream                = "http://localhost:4566"
    appsync                  = "http://localhost:4566"
    athena                   = "http://localhost:4566"
    autoscaling              = "http://localhost:4566"
    autoscalingplans         = "http://localhost:4566"
    backup                   = "http://localhost:4566"
    batch                    = "http://localhost:4566"
    budgets                  = "http://localhost:4566"
    cloud9                   = "http://localhost:4566"
    cloudformation           = "http://localhost:4566"
    cloudfront               = "http://localhost:4566"
    cloudhsm                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    cloudsearch              = "http://localhost:4566"
    cloudtrail               = "http://localhost:4566"
    cloudwatch               = "http://localhost:4566"
    cloudwatchevents         = "http://localhost:4566"
    cloudwatchlogs           = "http://localhost:4566"
    codeartifact             = "http://localhost:4566"
    codebuild                = "http://localhost:4566"
    codecommit               = "http://localhost:4566"
    codedeploy               = "http://localhost:4566"
    codepipeline             = "http://localhost:4566"
    cognitoidentity          = "http://localhost:4566"
    cognitoidp               = "http://localhost:4566"
    configservice            = "http://localhost:4566"
    cur                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    dataexchange             = "http://localhost:4566"
    datapipeline             = "http://localhost:4566"
    datasync                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    dax                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    devicefarm               = "http://localhost:4566"
    directconnect            = "http://localhost:4566"
    dlm                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    dms                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    docdb                    = "http://localhost:4566"
    ds                       = "http://localhost:4566"
    dynamodb                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    ec2                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    ecr                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    ecs                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    efs                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    eks                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    elasticache              = "http://localhost:4566"
    elasticbeanstalk         = "http://localhost:4566"
    elastictranscoder        = "http://localhost:4566"
    elb                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    emr                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    es                       = "http://localhost:4566"
    firehose                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    fms                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    forecast                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    fsx                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    gamelift                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    glacier                  = "http://localhost:4566"
    globalaccelerator        = "http://localhost:4566"
    glue                     = "http://localhost:4566"
    guardduty                = "http://localhost:4566"
    greengrass               = "http://localhost:4566"
    iam                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    identitystore            = "http://localhost:4566"
    imagebuilder             = "http://localhost:4566"
    inspector                = "http://localhost:4566"
    iot                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    iotanalytics             = "http://localhost:4566"
    iotevents                = "http://localhost:4566"
    kafka                    = "http://localhost:4566"
    kinesis                  = "http://localhost:4566"
    kinesisanalytics         = "http://localhost:4566"
    kinesisanalyticsv2       = "http://localhost:4566"
    kinesisvideo             = "http://localhost:4566"
    kms                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    lakeformation            = "http://localhost:4566"
    lambda                   = "http://localhost:4566"
    lexmodels                = "http://localhost:4566"
    licensemanager           = "http://localhost:4566"
    lightsail                = "http://localhost:4566"
    macie                    = "http://localhost:4566"
    managedblockchain        = "http://localhost:4566"
    marketplacecatalog       = "http://localhost:4566"
    mediaconnect             = "http://localhost:4566"
    mediaconvert             = "http://localhost:4566"
    medialive                = "http://localhost:4566"
    mediapackage             = "http://localhost:4566"
    mediastore               = "http://localhost:4566"
    mediastoredata           = "http://localhost:4566"
    mq                       = "http://localhost:4566"
    neptune                  = "http://localhost:4566"
    networkmanager           = "http://localhost:4566"
    opsworks                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    organizations            = "http://localhost:4566"
    outposts                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    personalize              = "http://localhost:4566"
    pinpoint                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    pricing                  = "http://localhost:4566"
    qldb                     = "http://localhost:4566"
    quicksight               = "http://localhost:4566"
    ram                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    rds                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    redshift                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    resourcegroups           = "http://localhost:4566"
    resourcegroupstaggingapi = "http://localhost:4566"
    route53                  = "http://localhost:4566"
    route53domains           = "http://localhost:4566"
    route53resolver          = "http://localhost:4566"
    s3                       = "http://localhost:4566"
    s3control                = "http://localhost:4566"
    sagemaker                = "http://localhost:4566"
    sdb                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    secretsmanager           = "http://localhost:4566"
    securityhub              = "http://localhost:4566"
    serverlessrepo           = "http://localhost:4566"
    servicecatalog           = "http://localhost:4566"
    servicediscovery         = "http://localhost:4566"
    servicequotas            = "http://localhost:4566"
    ses                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    shield                   = "http://localhost:4566"
    sns                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    sqs                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    ssm                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    ssoadmin                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    stepfunctions            = "http://localhost:4566"
    storagegateway           = "http://localhost:4566"
    sts                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    swf                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    synthetics               = "http://localhost:4566"
    transfer                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    waf                      = "http://localhost:4566"
    wafregional              = "http://localhost:4566"
    wafv2                    = "http://localhost:4566"
    worklink                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    workmail                 = "http://localhost:4566"
    workspaces               = "http://localhost:4566"
    xray                     = "http://localhost:4566"
  }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to code this? Because Localstack now exposes most services on the same endpoint, I was hoping for something like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region              = "ap-southeast-2"
  s3_force_path_style = true

  access_key                  = "fake"
  secret_key                  = "fake"
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_metadata_api_check     = true
  skip_requesting_account_id  = true

  endpoints {
    default = "http://localhost:4566"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it has been somewhat solved in 4.0.0 AWS provider version: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-4-upgrade#new-provider-arguments

Comment: Hi @MarkoE can you please be more specific? I'm struggling to find anything there that helps in my situation

Comment: Maybe try this, but I'm not sure if that will work with localstack: `provider "aws" { use_fips_endpoint = true }`

Comment: Hmm I did notice that how would you point it to localstack? There is not longer any reference to localhost:4566

Comment: Yeah, not sure really if that would work.

Comment: could you not set this in your `terraform.rc` file ? https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/config-file#provider-installation

Comment: Not exactly sure how I would do this @DarkMukke?